# I've generated an sql file full of inserts but can't find any documentation of executing this script from a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm creating a stored procedure that will delete all the data in my database and then insert the data from my sql file. The reason I am using the delete and insert instead of a restore is because a restore requires that no one is connected to the database where as deleting and inserting allows people to still be connected.

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DropAndRestore 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@filepath nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
Exec sp_MSFOREACHTABLE 'delete from ?
RESTORE DATABASE [landofbeds] -- These lines are what needs to be replaced
FROM DISK = @FilePath         --
END
GO
```

Comment: Then use a restore instead of delete/insert. Delete/insert *also* requires that everyone gets disconnected to avoid blocking. Restore is a lot faster which means people will have to wait for a far shorter time. You *can* disconnect people before restoring. And finally, if you have a Enterprise database you can perform [online restores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/online-restore-sql-server)

Comment: _"deleting and inserting allows people to still be connected"_ Yeah, and it shifts all the data from under their feet. And you think that's *better*?!

Comment: This is only for testing purposes and will be used with selenium so it needs to allow multiple connection.

Answer (score 0):

> The reason I am using the delete and insert instead of a restore is
>   because a restore requires that no one is connected to the database
>   where as deleting and inserting allows people to still be connected

If all you need is minimum downtime you can restore your database in `db_copy`. Then drop your db and rename `db_copy` to `db`.

Yes you should disconnect all the users to be able to `drop` your db,  but it will take minimum time, while if you `delete` your data the table will still be unavailable for the whole duration of the `delete`, and as `delete` is always fully logged your users will wait.

To launch your script you can use `xp_cmdshell` that calls `sqlcmd` with `-i`  but it's not a good idea. You have no control on your script execution and if something goes wrong you will have even more downtime for your users.

Does your tables have FK defined?

```
Exec sp_MSFOREACHTABLE 'delete from ?
```

will try to delete everything in order it decides and you may end up with errors when you try to delete rows that are referenced in other tables.

Answer (score 0):

To execute your sql file from Stored procedure .. you can use xp_cmdshell. See steps below

1. First Create a Batch File (C:\testApps\test.bat) and execute your sql file from there..
   e.g.
   osql -S TestSQlServer -E -I C:\testApps\test.sql > C:\testApps\tlog.txt
2. Then add this line to your Calling Stored procedure
        exec xp_cmdshell 'C:\testApps\test.bat'
3. Execute your procedure 
   **Please note you will need to enable xp_cmdshell

Answer (score -1):

You can use bulk insert like this:

`BULK INSERT landofbeds.dbo.SalesOrderDetail

   FROM '\\computer\share\folder\neworders.txt'`

Comment: this is useful for a single table but like I said I have a file that has all the insert statements in it. I just to run that file through a stored procedure.

Comment: is it a strict expectation about it to be delete and insert statements in a single file? why do not you just use csv files, one for every table?